# Join two[or three] vga cables?

Tags: vga, projector

I am supposed to do a presentation on next month using power point, and will be using a projector to present it. The projector can be connected to the laptop by a vga cable, my problem is that I do not have a vga cable of sufficient length(I need a vga cable of length 4m minimum), other wise I need to sit close to the projector to operate the pc which I do not like. I have a usb extension cable of 5m length and I have searched for a usb to vga adapter, but they don't fit my budget and they will be of no use after this function.

So, my question is, is it possible to join more than two vga cables (because I need a cable of minimum 4m long) by removing one end from each cable and join them?
What are the things that I need to be taken care of while doing this?

Note: I will be using the projector screen as an extension of my laptop screen

Comment: if you don't want to buy a longer cable try using vga couplers, a couple of them is likely cheaper than a 4m cable

Comment: @Kevin I have mentioned that if I buy anything except vga cables(I could get them from my friend)will be of no use to me after the function. Also, one coupler will cost me about $3, and I need 3 of them which cost me about $10, I cant afford this much.

Comment: Just so I've got this right, rather than getting some worthwhile adaptors or a longer cable, your answer is to completely destroy 3 or more cables, wasting 3 or more hours cutting the cables, stripping back the wires, joining and properly isolating each and every wire and then spending hours repairing and re-repairing the kludgy and delicate monstrosity after every time you move it. Sure it's possible, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a solution that will be under $10.  Do you have access to another laptop on hand or is it really a $10 budget?

Comment: @NelsonChan Why are you asking for another laptop?

Comment: Remote connection via network, but that's assuming a budget of more than $10.  Obviously I do not recommend buying a laptop to do this, but I don't know what other resources they have.

Comment: Does the owner / operator of the beamer not have a long VGA cable? You won't be the only person giving a talk there?!

Comment: How about using your phone to control your laptop?

Comment: @AEonAX It's not applicable here.

Comment: You seem to need volume control and presentation control. That you can easily do with a phone.

Comment: Try Touchpad - http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thingsstuff.touchpad It provides volume control through phone's volume key as well media and browser control. Controls windows from android though.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly, but perhaps you haven't thought of that:

Ask a friends (whose laptop you use anyhow), collegue, or somebody who listens to the talk. (S)He can  easily advance the slides for you via a *THz, i.e. visual, connection* `;)`.

I've done that a lot of times myself, ideally you should train the talk before with that person, then there's even no sign necessary when you want the next slide. Sometimes it's even helpful as a hint that you forgot something important to mention when the next slide *will not appear*.

Of course, it's not possible in all circumstances... but if it's an important talk you should consider to invest some money. My recommondation is a *wireless mouse* (check if the operating range is large enough, 4 metres might be difficult), I've seen one for US$ 3 on eBay.

Comment: It's my mistake, I didn't give the full details with the question. The situation is , we want to give a farewell party to our seniors, so we need a laptop to control the sound for the program and to play songs etc, along with that I would like to play a slide show or a video on the screen using the projector( by extending the screen to projector), but if the cable is not long enough, I have to sit near to the projector, i.e in-front of the stage, which is an inconvenience to the audiance because all the time something will be staging.

Comment: @RogUE: I see, I've only read the buzzwords _powerpoint_ and _presentation_ and immediately thought of a talk...